# How to handle NSData as a @property

Tags: objective-c, properties

I'm trying to get a @property to work with NSData so that it becomes available to all methods in the class.

I've set up a little test project to help me debug the problem.

In my `main.m` is

```
FxPlug *data = [[FxPlug alloc] init];  
[FxPlug makeCube];  
NSLog (@"%@",[FxPlug.cubeData]);
```

and in the Class `FxPlug.h` is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface FxPlug : NSObject
@property NSData *cubeData;
+(void) makeCube;
@end
```

and `FxPlug.m` is

```
#import "FxPlug.h"
@implementation FxPlug

+ (void) makeCube; {
NSString *filePath = @"/Development/testNSDataProperty/test_cube_data.dat";
NSData *cubeData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}
@end
```

So this is just a test to see if I can set the `@property NSData *cubeData;` in class `FxPlug` to the contents of a file and to see if it is passed back into the `main.m` class to `NSLog` out to the terminal.

I'd be really really appreciative of some help.

Basically, I'm trying to pass an NSData object between classes.

Many thanks!

Because my main project is an FxPlug, which is basically just one big class with a load of methods that are named specifically for the host app. So I need to add a new class method to that existing class to handle the NSData object. Or at least that's how I think it works!

Comment: Why are you trying to use a class method to setup a property that is only available to a specific instance of the class?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a property then you have to use and create a class *instance* and avoid using class methods, so:

FxPlug.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface FxPlug : NSObject
@property NSData *cubeData;
-(void) makeCube;
@end
```

FxPlug.m:

```
#import "FxPlug.h"
@implementation FxPlug

- (void) makeCube {
    NSString *filePath = @"/Development/testNSDataProperty/test_cube_data.dat";
    self.cubeData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}
@end
```

main.m:

```
FxPlug *data = [[FxPlug alloc] init];  
[data makeCube];  
NSLog (@"%@", data.cubeData);
```

It can be done with class methods, and class-level variables, but not with `@property`s.  One halfway house is to use the singleton pattern where you only allow one instance of the class to exist at any one time.

**EDIT**: If you want to do it as a static class (not recommended), the code is below:

FxPlug.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface FxPlug : NSObject
+ (NSData *)cubeData;
+ (void)setCubeData:(NSData *)cubeData;
+ (void) makeCube;
@end
```

FxPlug.m:

```
#import "FxPlug.h"

static NSData *_cubeData = nil;

@implementation FxPlug

+ (NSData *)cubeData
{
    return _cubeData;
}

+ (void)setCubeData:(NSData *)cubeData
{
    _cubeData = cubeData;
}

+ (void) makeCube {
    NSString *filePath = @"/Development/testNSDataProperty/test_cube_data.dat";
    _cubeData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}
@end
```

main.m:

```
[FxPlug makeCube];  
NSLog (@"%@", [FxPlug cubeData]);
```

Comment: I think I understand, but could you give an example of the singleton pattern?

Comment: @JonathanRichards There are many examples around. [This one](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) seems particularly good.

Comment: You know, I actually think the existent FxPlug I'm developing is a singleton. The mention of Pragma (whatever that is!) appears in the .m file

Comment: @JonathanRichards That `#pragma mark` is simply a comment to allow sections of a file to be organised easier in Xcode.  It's got nothing to do with singletons.

Comment: Would it be better to use `extern` for the NSData?

Comment: Not for a singleton pattern, no.

Comment: Sorry. I mean instead of a Singleton?

Comment: No, the `NSData` would be `static` and accessed by the class methods only.  You would need to provide surrogate getter and setter methods.

Comment: Oh! Out of my depth now!

Comment: @JonathanRichards Done.

Comment: Cool. Let me take a look

Comment: @JonathanRichards No, a singleton is something different.  Use the link I provided earlier.

Comment: What is the `setCubeData` method doing?

Comment: @JonathanRichards It allows the `cubeData` to be set.  Your `@property` didn't include the `readonly` attribute, so I included a setter method.

Comment: Is that method automatically called or do I need to call it?

Comment: That question doesn't really make any sense.  I think that's enough about this answer now thanks.  I am getting no love and it just wasting my time.

Comment: I'm really sorry, that's not my intention at all!!!! Far from it. I really appreciate you helping!